# Derived state with Apollo Client and apollo-link-state

Tags: apollo-client

What's the best way to observe derived state with apollo-link-state?

As a contrived example, the cache stores a list of Todo items. Another component needs to track the total count of Todo items.

Storing `totalTodos` in local state would be less than ideal because each resolver function (`updateTodo`, `deleteTodo`, `addTodo`) would have to write to the cache and update `totalTodos`

```
query {
  totalTodos 
  todos { ...
```

Would be nice if there was a way to expose observable computed values?

Comment: You might be able to use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) for this, but I am not sure.